# Sending POST request in Android ( Java) using Retrofit,.. working similar to following python code

Tags: java, android, python, retrofit

I need to call an API from android application but can't get it working.. Same   py code works fine..
How to port the following python code in Android using Retrofit?

```
import requests
import json

head = {'X-API-KEY':'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
args = {'item1', 'value'}

c = requests.post("http_link",data=json.dumps(args),headers=head)
print(c.text)
```

If solution is available without Using the retrofit library please do share.
I tried to implement the above python code in the application using the retrofit library in the following way... 
Interface :

```
public interface Safety_aws_api {
    String BASE_URL = "httplink";
    @Headers("{X-API-KEY:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}")
    @POST("Apisender")
    Call<ModelApiResponse> getApi(@Body Model_ApiCaller model_apiCaller);
}
```

Model Classes :

```
public class Model_ApiCaller {
    public String getApiName() {
        return apiName;
    }

    public void setApiName(String apiName) {
        this.apiName = apiName;
    }

    private String apiName;
    public Model_ApiCaller( String apiName){
        this.apiName = apiName;
    }

    public Model_ApiCaller(){

    }
}


public class ModelApiResponse {
    private String types, Api;

    public String getTypes() {
        return types;
    }

    public void setTypes(String types) {
        this.types = types;
    }

    public String getApi() {
        return Api;
    }

    public void setApi(String api) {
        Api = api;
    }
}
```

Helper class :

```
 public class RetroHelper {

      private static Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Safety_aws_api.BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

      public static Safety_aws_api api = retrofit.create(Safety_aws_api.class);
}
```

Calling Function :

```
private void getCodes( Model_ApiCaller model_apiCaller) {
    Call<ModelApiResponse> call = RetroHelper.api.getApi(model_apiCaller);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ModelApiResponse>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ModelApiResponse> call, Response<ModelApiResponse> response) {
            tv_sample_data.setText( response.body().getApi());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ModelApiResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "errr", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            tv_sample_data.setText("erererer");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: have you worked through any Retrofit tutorial?

Comment: @dson9966 Plese share your android code of API request.

Comment: @Jay added my code

Comment: @luk2302 I did some searches to compile the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Interface (Changed ,thanks to @Jay for @Header suggestion) finally added RequestBody type body to make it work:

```
public interface Safety_aws_api {
    String BASE_URL = "httplink";
    @POST("Apisender")
    Call<List<ModelApiResponse>> getApi(@Header("x-api-key") String apiKey, @Body RequestBody body);
}
```

Model Classes :

```
public class Model_ApiCaller {
    public String getApiName() {
        return apiName;
    }

    public void setApiName(String apiName) {
        this.apiName = apiName;
    }

    private String apiName;
    public Model_ApiCaller( String apiName){
        this.apiName = apiName;
    }

    public Model_ApiCaller(){

    }
}


public class ModelApiResponse {
    private String types, Api;

    public String getTypes() {
        return types;
    }

    public void setTypes(String types) {
        this.types = types;
    }

    public String getApi() {
        return Api;
    }

    public void setApi(String api) {
        Api = api;
    }
}
```

Helper class :

```
 public class RetroHelper {

      private static Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Safety_aws_api.BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

      public static Safety_aws_api api = retrofit.create(Safety_aws_api.class);
}
```

**Calling Function (Changed "ModelApiResponse" to "List(ModelApiResponse)"):

```
 private void getCodes( Model_ApiCaller model_apiCaller) {
    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream");
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\"types\":\""+ model_apiCaller.getApiName()+"\"}");
    Call<List<ModelApiResponse>> call = null;
    call = RetroHelper.api.getApi("api_key",body);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ModelApiResponse>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<ModelApiResponse>> call, Response<List<ModelApiResponse>> response) {
            try {
                tv_sample_data.setText( response.body().get(0).getApi());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+e.toString());

            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+response.code());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<ModelApiResponse>> call, Throwable t) {
            tv_sample_data.setText("erererer!!!!");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add header with below code. If output is same please share your current response of  API call.

```
   Call<ModelApiResponse> getApi(@Header("X-Authorization") String apiKey,@Body Model_ApiCaller model_apiCaller);
```

Comment: Are you getting any crash or error?? Please share that.

Comment: no response code is 200.. no crashes. just not getting the result as I get using the python code.

Comment: Check your Model_ApiCaller  class is it containing the args = {'item1', 'value'} part of python and also go though retrofit example again.